Crontab isn't working with reboot parameter
I did a crontab job for my user with crontab -l. After that I ran crontab -e and selected Nano.
Then I entered my command:
@reboot expressvpn connect "USA - Michigan"

When I login with my user it doesn't work. Every time I login I need to open a terminal and write that command.
I don't see any log or anything that would help me to investigate my problem.

You've not provided release details (I'll thus assume 24.10) but have you tried setting that commands as an autostart via your login; ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html in the Lubuntu manual (scroll down to autostart).  The URL for the manual link I provided is for 24.10; adjust if you're using another release; as you didn't specify release; the expressvpn may require a fully functional networking; this may allow for it where your reboot may not

yeah its the latest native 24.10. i will look into the manual and try it that way. thank you

I removed the crontab job and familiarized myself with the command from @guiverc.
For future users, here’s a quick tutorial:

Click on the Lubuntu logo.
Go to Preferences → LxQt Settings → Session Settings.
Go to Autostart and click Add.
Simply provide a name and enter the command or select a file to load.
Restart, and you're done!

